# Flutter Firestore save value as string

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save a value from my Cloud Firestore as a string. I am using Flutter with Dart. I have been able to save it when building the page using MaterialepageRoute:

```
        MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MainScreen(
              currentUserId: firebaseUser.uid,
              currentUserGender: document['gender'],
              currentUserPreference: document['preference'],
            )),
```

But this isn't an option with all of my pages, so I have to look for something else. I want to get the value from my Firestore Database, and then save it as a string, since I want to:

```
if (currentUserGender == 'male') {
//then do something 
}
```

I am able to get the currentUser. Here is a picture of my database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO7oi.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your models after query your user 
each get of an item in firestore results in a map of key as string and object:
so you have to recreate your object like this. (this is an example)
Either you can create factory methods in your entity class to create an object back from json or create a map from your object.

```
class UsersEntityAdapters implements EntityAdapters<UsersEntity> {

@override
UsersEntity toEntity(Map<String, dynamic> map, String id) {
    return new UsersEntity(id,
        map['name'],
        map['birthday'],
        map['gender'],
        map['description'],
        map['urlPhotoPublic'],
        map['urlPhotoStorage'],
        nbFaves: map['nbFaves'],
    );
}

@override
Map<String, dynamic> toMap(UsersEntity entity) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = new Map();
    map.putIfAbsent('name', () => entity.name);
    map.putIfAbsent('birthday', () => entity.birthday);
    map.putIfAbsent('gender', () => entity.gender);
    map.putIfAbsent('description', () => entity.description);
    map.putIfAbsent('urlPhotoPublic', () => entity.urlPhotoPublic);
    map.putIfAbsent('urlPhotoStorage', () => entity.urlPhotoStorage);
    map.putIfAbsent('deviceToken', () => entity.deviceToken);
    map.putIfAbsent('nbFaves', () => entity.nbFaves);
    return map;
}
}
```